# Retrieve value of a Jquery variable name containing a variable in itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

In the top of my Jquery I've got many variables (associated with values) called : files_1, files_2, etc.

They are created in a script, in the bottom of my page :

```
<script>
$(function () {
    <?php foreach ($folders as $f) { ?>
    var files_<?=$f['request_id']?> = 0;
    <?php } ?>
    …
});
</script>
```

In my html I've got a link like :

```
<a href="#" class="delete" data-request-id="2" title="delete">Delete</a>
```

data-request-id parameter gives me a number, the ones you've got in my variables names on top. In my example, it's data-request-id="**2**" : files_**2**.

Next, I've got a Jquery function that catch data values from links :

```
$('.request-files').on('click', 'a.delete', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $link = $(this);
    var $id = $link.data('request-id');
    console.log(files_$id); // <-- It doesn't work
});
```

What I need to do is to retrieve the value of the variables **files_x**. In my example, I tried to get them using **files_$id** but it doesn't work.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have your variables defined in the global scrope, they are attached to the `window` object. So you should be able to access your variables by using bracket notation on the window object:

```
$('.request-files').on('click', 'a.delete', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $link = $(this);
    var $id = $link.data('request-id');
    console.log(window['files_' + $id]); // <-- It DOES work
});
```

**UPD**: your variables are in the closure of document.ready function (`$(function() {...});`), so you won't be able to access them from other scopes. I assume that your click handler is within that closure as well. I can suggest creating a separate object with properties named `file_<ID>` - it will work much alike as with window:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    var filesMap = {};
    <?php foreach ($folders as $f) { ?>
    filesMap['files_' + <?=$f['request_id']?>] = 0;
    <?php } ?>
    …
    $('.request-files').on('click', 'a.delete', function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var $link = $(this);
       var $id = $link.data('request-id');
       console.log(filesMap['files_' + $id]); 
    });
});
</script>
```

I am not familiar with PHP, so the string concatenation in `request_id` part might be different, but the logic remains.

Comment: I've edited my question because it didn't work for me. Maybe I missed something.